# grep -w with only space as delimiter

Tags: unix, grep, cpu-word

```
grep -w uses punctuations and whitespaces as delimiters.
```

How can I set grep to only use whitespaces as a delimiter for a word?

Comment: Please improve your question by posting the relevant sections of code you've tried, [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). In addition, please post whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against.

Comment: the question is very simple and does require a code to be pasted. It's a theoretical question. William Pursell understood it and answered it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match *just* spaces: `grep -w foo` is the same as `grep " foo "`.  If you also want to match line endings or tabs you can start doing things like: `grep '\(^\| \)foo\($\| \)'`, but you're probably better off with `perl -ne 'print if /\sfoo\s/'`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the way `grep -w` works. However, you can replace punctuations with, say, `X` character using `tr` or `sed` and then use `grep -w`, that will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The --word-regexp flag is useful, but limited. The grep man page says:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

If you want to use custom field separators, awk may be a better fit for you. Or you could just write an extended regular expression with egrep or `grep --extended-regexp` that gives you more control over your search pattern.

Comment: how can i do it with awk? i want to search for a particular word in a line. if it is there i have to consider the line else ignore it

Comment: @ganducoder Please update your question with the relevant section of the code that you're currently working on; folks will be glad to help, but won't write it for you. In addition, include whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` to replace spaces with new lines. Then `grep` your string. The contiguous string I needed was being split up with `grep -w` because it has colons in it. Furthermore, I only knew the first part, and the second part was the unknown data I needed to pull. Therefore, the following helped me.

```
echo "$your_content" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep 'string'
```