# how to match a whole substring with delimiter in bash

Tags: grep

I have a String like this

```
"ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP"
```

I get user input to match with each of these substrings as whole and not part.
How do I do this?

This is what I am doing currently

```
printf "\n Enter user input:"

read userinput

INPUT=$userinput

if echo "ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP" | grep -q "$INPUT"; then
  echo "Matching...";
else

  echo "Invalid entry ";
fi
```

The problem with the above code is it will match a partial substring like `"ABC"`,

`"GH`" etc which I do not want. I just need the user input to compare with whole substrings separated by delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-w` to match an entire word in `grep`

```
echo "ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP" | grep -w "$INPUT";
```

**Example**

```
>>> INPUT=ABC
>>> echo "ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP" | grep -w "$INPUT";
>>>
>>> INPUT=ABCD
>>> echo "ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP" | grep -w "$INPUT";
ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP
```

Answer (score 1):

> grep -w

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

Similar link: [grep -w with only space as delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931370/grep-w-with-only-space-as-delimiter)