# Shell script variables in usage with grep command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am scripting on an ansible-deployment project, it's almost done, just fixing bugs.
One option of this script is version checking of a previously specified program (e.g. fontconfig) Ansible gives following output:

```
PLAY [all] 
********************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [192.168.40.132]
ok: [192.168.40.133]
ok: [192.168.40.134]
ok: [192.168.40.135]

TASK: [Find affected package] *************************************************
changed: [192.168.40.135]
changed: [192.168.40.132]
changed: [192.168.40.133]
changed: [192.168.40.134]

TASK: [debug var=dpkg.stdout_lines] *******************************************
ok: [192.168.40.132] => {
"dpkg.stdout_lines": [
    "ii  fontconfig                    2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           i386         generic font configuration library - support binaries",
    "ii  fontconfig-config             2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           all          generic font configuration library - configuration",
    "ii  libfontconfig1:i386           2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           i386         generic font configuration library - runtime"
]
}
ok: [192.168.40.133] => {
"dpkg.stdout_lines": [
    "ii  fontconfig                    2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           i386         generic font configuration library - support binaries",
    "ii  fontconfig-config             2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           all          generic font configuration library - configuration",
    "ii  libfontconfig1:i386           2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           i386         generic font configuration library - runtime"
]
}
ok: [192.168.40.134] => {
"dpkg.stdout_lines": [
    "ii  fontconfig                     2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           amd64        generic font configuration library - support binaries",
    "ii  fontconfig-config              2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           all          generic font configuration library - configuration",
    "ii  libfontconfig1:amd64           2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1           amd64        generic font configuration library - runtime"
]
}
ok: [192.168.40.135] => {
"dpkg.stdout_lines": [
    "rc  fontconfig                     2.11.0-6.3                  amd64        generic font configuration library - support binaries",
    "rc  fontconfig-config              2.11.0-6.3                  all          generic font configuration library - configuration",
    "rc  libfontconfig1:amd64           2.11.0-6.3                  amd64        generic font configuration library - runtime"
]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
192.168.40.132             : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
192.168.40.133             : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
192.168.40.134             : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
192.168.40.135             : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I am want to filter out the IP-Addresses containing e.g the servers with version 2.11.0-6.3, but not with 2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1.
Currently I am filtering with following command ($ver is previously read from direct input):

```
cat output.txt | grep -B 3 $ver
```

so good, so far ok, but above mentioned case does not work.
So I tried using

```
part1="'(^| )";
part2="( |$)'";
done=$part1$ver$part2;
cat output.txt | grep -E $done -B 3
```

But getting an error:

```
grep: »(« or »\(« without closing bracket
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Usage of

```
cat output.txt | grep -E "$done" -B 3
```

or

```
cat output.txt | grep -E '$done' -B 3
```

works, but I don't get any output.

Please help.
Thank you!

Comment: so `$ver` is 2.11.0-6.3, right? Note also that `cat file | grep XX` can be written to just `grep XX file`. Also, `grep -E '$done' -B 3` won't work because variable within single quotes are not expanded; you need to use double quotes -> `grep -E "$done" -B 3` as your first attempt shows.

Comment: $ver could be anything, this is a user input. 
the cat output.txt is just simplified for here, actually this is a return value from an ansible-playbook command.
But why doesn't the command work as wished with double quotes ?

Comment: But why don't you just say `grep -wE "(^| )$var( |$)" file`? Storing parts of the regex in vars makes it more complicated. Unless you want to do something more complex, I don't see any benefit on it.

Comment: @msperl What is the end goal?  Do you want, as mentioned one place, just the IP addresses?  Or do you want all the surrounding info that `grep -B 3` prints?

Comment: will try this, thx btw...

Comment: @John1024: I just want the IP-Address, this filter is already implemented and working

Comment: Why does you regex have single quotes in it?

Comment: @123: Saw this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931370/grep-w-with-only-space-as-delimiter
to all: thanks for your help!

Comment: @msperl What does that have to do with single quotes in regex?

Comment: I thought, it would be necessary. I am relatively new to linux shell scripting, getting most information from the internet to get the scripts done.
Also saw this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186543/how-to-grep-exact-word-with-only-space-as-word-separator

Comment: Remove the single quotes and it should work when double quoted.

Comment: One problem solved, other problem made: When I search for 2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1 no results will be found. Any suggestions?

Comment: @msperl escape special character i.e `+.`

Comment: @123 will this cover my entire problem too? If I escape the "+"-Sign, it will output all the other version numbers too when I'm searching for 2.11.0-6.3+deb8u1, right?

Comment: No, because it won't match the others anymore...

Comment: Mhm.. ok. Could you give me an example how to escape the + sign? 
Would appreciate much.

Comment: @123: Any suggestions about escaping the +-Sign?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get just the IP addresses that match `2.11.0-6.3`, try:

```
$ awk  '/ 2.11.0-6.3 /{print $1}' RS='ok:' output.txt
[192.168.40.135]
```

To specify the version with a shell variable:

```
$ ver='2.11.0-6.3'
$ awk -v ver="$ver"  '$0~(" " ver " "){print $1}' RS='ok:' output.txt
[192.168.40.135]
```

Note that `ver` is treated as a regex.  That means that regex-active characters like `+` would have to be escaped.

Comment: @msperl This eliminates entirely the need for the `grep` command.  So, this addresses the question raised here.

Comment: Could this one be splitted into two steps? In one module of the program I need the full output of ansible. The other part, which is entirely designed to find old versions and update them to newer versions executes the first and filters the output for IP-addresses, puts them into a formatted file that is recognized by ansible as a valid hosts-file. After this step the update of the specified program begins on the selected servers.

Comment: _"Could this one be splitted into two steps?"_  I expect that the answer is yes but the details are not clear to me.  To clarify, you want to save _"full output of ansible"_.  Isn't that is what `output.txt` is?  And, `output.txt` can be used more than once?  Or, is something else going on?

Comment: output.txt is just here to keep it a bit simpler.
In reality this does not exists, it's an very long ansible-playbook command with lots of parameters. output.txt is just imaginary here